# Scala inner case class in subclass parameter compilation error

Tags: scala, lift, html-email

I want to set body of Html email from String, not Xml Node for Lift Mailer, so I subclassed Mailer and redefined `buildMailBody` method:

```
class HtmlMailer extends Mailer {
  final case class HtmlMailBodyType(text: String) extends MailBodyType

  override protected def buildMailBody(tab: MailBodyType) = {
    tab match {
      case HtmlMailBodyType(text) =>
        val bp = new MimeBodyPart
        bp.setText(text, charSet, "html")
        bp
      case _ => super.buildMailBody(tab)
    }
  }
}

object HtmlMailer extends HtmlMailer
```

When I try to use it:

```
import net.liftweb.util.Mailer
import Mailer._    

HtmlMailer.sendMail(From(sender.email), Subject(subject), To(user.email), HtmlMailBodyType(body))
```

I get compilation error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : net.liftweb.util.Mailer.From
required: com.mypackage.HtmlMailer.From
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
HtmlMailer.sendMail(From(sender.email), Subject(subject), To(user.email), HtmlMailBodyType(body))
```

Why is this happeing and how can I fix it correctly?

I changed import Mailer._    to  import HtmlMailer._ and it worked, but I beleive it breaks Liskov substitution principle, as I cannot substitute `HtmlMailer` instead of `Mailer`, because they have different parameter types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble with path dependent types and singletons. When you have nested classes, each *instance* of the outer class has a *different* instance of the nested class.

Now, the `From` (plus `Subject`, `To`, etc), since they are nested, belong to a specific instance. In this case, you have two instances providing them. They are the *objects*:

```
net.liftweb.util.Mailer
com.mypackage.HtmlMailer
```

Note that these are not *classes*, they are *objects*.

Now, the method `sendMail` requires that its parameters be composed of classes belonging to *the same instance as itself*. There are many reasons for making such a requirement, as there are ways of not making it.

So, really, there's no violation of the liskov substitution principle here, just a violation of type that has been hidden by the import. If you write it out explicitly, it becomes clearer:

```
val myInst: net.liftweb.util.Mailer = HtmlMailer
myInst.sendMail(myInst.From(sender.email), myInst.Subject(subject), myInst.To(user.email), myInst.HtmlMailBodyType(body))
```

You can replace `HtmlMailer` there with `net.liftweb.util.Mailer` or any other instance of `net.liftweb.util.Mailer` and it will work. You *cannot* use two different instances of `net.liftweb.util.Mailer`, even if they are both of the very same class.